# Using reflection to instantiate control properties inside an object

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, dynamic, instantiation

I'm testing logic in pre-existing code that I can't easily go and edit, but the object that the code resides in has 50+ objects inside of it that are null for whatever reason. What I'm looking to do is: from my test code, using reflection, go through all the inner objects of the class I'm testing and if said object is null then just instantiate it. This is what I have thus far:

```
Type ucApprovedType = ucApproved.GetType();
System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] fieldInfo = ucApprovedType.GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo ucFieldInfo in fieldInfo)
{
    Control control = ucApproved.FindControl(ucFieldInfo.Name);

    if (control == null)
        control = new Control();

    //Set instantiated control back to ucApproved item
}
```

The first issue I'm running into above is that the control is coming back null from the FindControl(ucFieldInfo.Name) call. Then once I have the instatiated control, I don't know how to set it's value back into the ucApproved object, since I can't do `ucApproved.Controls[0] = control` because the ControlCollection is read-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, but its easier to use the fieldInfo objects directly to reference the objects in question.  Try this:

```
Type ucApprovedType = ucApproved.GetType();
System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] fieldInfo = ucApprovedType.GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo ucFieldInfo in fieldInfo)
{
    //get its current value
    Control control = ucFieldInfo.GetValue(ucApproved) as Control;

    if (control == null)
    {
        control = new Control();

        //Set instantiated control back to ucApproved item
        ucFieldInfo.SetValue(ucApproved, control);
    }
}
```

**Warning**
this really only works as is if the ONLY fields that you get in this loop are `Control` fields.  Otherwise you need to add a filter statement.

```
if (ucFieldInfo.FieldType.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(Control)) || ucFieldInfo.FieldType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Control)))
```

or similar.

**-------another option-----------**

With the assumption that ucApproved is a custom user control, why not just make a public utility function inside the control class that will instanciate the controls for you.

Yes, I can see that you said "cannot easily go and edit".  I even understand the concept.  It is however, the easier answer. Calling `ucApproved.CreateControls();` would be a much cleaner solution.

Comment: This worked wonderfully! (qualifying for different types of Controls) Thanks a lot!